# Creating Html table with javascript function using firestore collections

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, javascript-objects

I'm building a basic html admin panel for my firebase. I created a javascript function to get value from firestore and set in a html table. If My all values in the same collection then I can get this values and put it in a html table with success. But If I have to use two collections in same time then I got problem. To give more details, I'm getting my **NonAttendance** values from firestore and I want to show student name and surname in the html table. My nonAttendance collection has only **user id** in **STUDENTS** array and I want to get students info from  **Users** table using this **id**. I think I got the problem, it's about **promise** When I use **async** function or **.then()**, Table show nothing, when I don't use any promise and text something in table instead of firestore value, then Table shows them. My javascript function is:

```
function GetClassNonAttendaceInfoDetail(NonAttendaceInfoID){

//console.log("CLASs===>",NonAttendaceInfoID);
const REF_DATABASE = db.collection("NonAttendance").doc(NonAttendaceInfoID);
REF_DATABASE.get().then((doc) => {

    var showClassNonAttendanceInfo = document.getElementById('showClassNonAttendanceInfo');
    var showClassNonAttendanceInfoDetail = document.getElementById('showClassNonAttendanceInfoDetail');

    showClassNonAttendanceInfo.hidden = true;
    showClassNonAttendanceInfoDetail.style.visibility = 'visible';

    var students = doc.data().STUDENTS;
    //console.log(students);

    var html = '<table class="data-table table nowrap"><thead><tr>';
    html +=
        '                        <th>CLASS</th>\n' +
        '                        <th>STUDENT NO</th>\n' +
        '                        <th>NAME_SURNAME</th>\n' ;
    html += '</tr></thead><tbody>';


    students.forEach(async index => {
        const REF = await db.collection("Users").doc(index).get();
        //console.log(REF.data().NAME);
             
        html += '<tr>';

        html += '<td>' + REF.data().CLASS + '</td>';
        html += '<td>' + REF.data().STUDENT_NO + '</td>';
        html += '<td>' + REF.data().NAME +' '+ REF.data().NAME+ '</td>';

        html += '</tr>';   
        console.log(REF.data());
    
    })
    html += '</tbody></table>';
    showClassNonAttendanceInfoDetail.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);

}).catch(()=>{
    console.log("Hata")
})
}
```

[This is the google chrome console screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwCJK.png)

As you see in the picture, in the right side I got my all value from firestore with success, But I can't put it in the table which is left side.

[My NonAttendance Collection in Firestore screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuigQ.png)
This is my example of NonAttendance collection of firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `forEach` does not support `async`. To solve your problem you sould store the indexes into an array and loop over them with a `for` loop because those support `async`. Your code would look like this:

```js
function GetClassNonAttendaceInfoDetail(NonAttendaceInfoID) {
  //console.log("CLASs===>",NonAttendaceInfoID);
  const REF_DATABASE = db.collection("NonAttendance").doc(NonAttendaceInfoID);
  REF_DATABASE.get()
    .then((doc) => {
      var showClassNonAttendanceInfo = document.getElementById(
        "showClassNonAttendanceInfo"
      );
      var showClassNonAttendanceInfoDetail = document.getElementById(
        "showClassNonAttendanceInfoDetail"
      );

      showClassNonAttendanceInfo.hidden = true;
      showClassNonAttendanceInfoDetail.style.visibility = "visible";

      var students = doc.data().STUDENTS;
      //console.log(students);

      var html = '<table class="data-table table nowrap"><thead><tr>';
      html +=
        "                        <th>CLASS</th>\n" +
        "                        <th>STUDENT NO</th>\n" +
        "                        <th>NAME_SURNAME</th>\n";
      html += "</tr></thead><tbody>";

      var indexes = [];

      students.forEach((i) => {
        indexes.push(i);
      });

      for (let i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
        const index = indexes[i];

        const REF = await db.collection("Users").doc(index).get();
        //console.log(REF.data().NAME);

        html += "<tr>";

        html += "<td>" + REF.data().CLASS + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + REF.data().STUDENT_NO + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + REF.data().NAME + " " + REF.data().NAME + "</td>";

        html += "</tr>";
        console.log(REF.data());
      }

      html += "</tbody></table>";
      showClassNonAttendanceInfoDetail.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log("Hata");
    });
}
```

Comment: You saved my days. Thank you so much. You just forgot to add **async**. After I added it, it worked perfectly.

Comment: One question more I want to ask. I created html table in the function and it works perfectly when I click the button one time. But if  I click the button second time to call new values, first table is still on page and second table is coming below the first table. I want first table remove when I click second time.

Comment: I solved my another question. Thanks again for helping.

Comment: Sorry. Somehow your commend went under my radar. Didn't notice it. Sorry again.